# NDK integration is deprecated in Android 1.5 - Open Camera

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am trying to run this [OpenCamera](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera) project.

I have imported this project to Android Studio as Eclipse Project. Android has made its gradle build for the Project.

During the build project I got this error

Error:(12, 0) Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration. Open Build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.almalence.opencam"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "OpenCamera-master"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/androidexiv2.jar')
    compile files('libs/openiab-0.9.8.6.jar')
}
```

I have also added Deprecation to the gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Kindly help me solve this issue at the earliest I want to test this application on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out the solution. Gradle.properties file wasn't created. So I manually created the Gradle.properties file by right clicking on the Module create new file and named the file as gradle.properties and added android.useDeprecatedNdk=true